# javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate issue with returns null value

Tags: tomcat, pom.xml, x509certificate, web.xml

When I try to run the following code from my Eclipse, I always get the return value as null:

```
    X509Certificate cert[] = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
System.out.println("cert: " + cert[0]); //always returns null
```

Could someone assist me with this issue? I read somewhere saying that I have to set the client authentication value to true, but how do I do that? I use pom.xml and web.xml (attached below)

```
web.xml:
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>HTTPS<web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*<url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>

pom.xml:
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
  <keystoreFile>${basedir}/certs/keystore.jks</keystoreFile>
  <keystorePass>changeit</keystorePass>
</configuration>
```

Any help is really appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client authentication is false by default.  You should be able to use this property to make it true:

```
maven.tomcat.https.clientAuth
```

You can find more [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-war-only-mojo.html#clientAuth).

Note that this property is only available in version 2.1 of the plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was able to set the clientAuth to true using the link you provided. However, now I got the "SSL peer cannot verify your certificate" error.

Comment: You probably need to set up a trust keystore, so the server/client know which certificates to trust.

Comment: YES!! including trust keystore did the trick.. Thanks for your help!!